# Matlab: Loop over files, plot data in one figure & add file names as legend

Tags: matlab, loops, plot, matlab-figure

I have a folder with several files, each of them containing some hundreds of data pairs (resistance R over Temperature T). The files do not contain the same amount of data points...
I want Matlab to read in the files, loop over them and plot R(T) of every single file, but all in one figure. Moreover, I want the file names as legends for the different graphs (eg, the plot resulting form file 'Example1.dat' should be indicated as 'Example1.dat' in the legend).
What I am doing right now is the following:

```
files=dir('*.dat') % Get all input files
hold on % multiple plots in one figure
for file=files' % loop over files
    [T, R] = textread(file.name,'%f %f') %get data points
    xlim([8.5 10]) % set limits
    ylim([-0.5 2.5]) % set limits
    plot(T,R) % plot
end
legend(files.name) % add legend
```

What I get does not look right, because every time I try it, the same graph gets a different name in the legend. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "every time I try it, the same graph gets a different name in the legend." part?

Comment: Well, the same graph in the plot (for example the one resulting from file 'Example1.dat') gets the name 'Example4.dat' on the first trial, and the  name 'Example1.dat' if I rerun the code...
Obviously, this is not what I want. If the graph results from file XY, it shoulkd get the name XY and not a different one...

Comment: Tried your code with dummy files and it worked fine every time.

Comment: I'd stack the data from different files to a cell array then plot once.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
files=dir('*.dat') % Get all input files
hold on % multiple plots in one figure
for filenumber=1:length(files) % loop over files
    [T, R] = textread(files(filenumber).name,'%f %f') %get data points
    plot(T,R) % plot
end
%limits only need to be fixed at the end
xlim([8.5 10]) % set limits
ylim([-0.5 2.5]) % set limits
legend(files.name) % add legend
```